# Url rewriting in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, url-rewriting, zend-route

I currently have url like localhost/zend_practice/countries/index?data=1 where countries is the name of my controller and index is name of my action.
I would like to have url like localhost/zend_practice/countries/index/data/1.
Also a rule to accept numbers only for the get parameter 'data'.
How can i do this for 'countries' controller only (not for my other controller)?

Comment: rtfm: [The Standard Router](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html)

Comment: are getting this URL with form submission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zend Framework by default takes url as

> /controller/action/parameter_name/parameter_value

You can directly use your url as

> /countries/index/data/1

and in the code you can get the data parameter and apply your logic as required.
Here's a snippet.

```
class CountriesController extends Zend_Controller_Action{
    public function indexAction(){
        //capture the data parameter
        $data = $this->_request->getParam('data');
        //check data if numeric
        if(is_numeric($data)){
            //your code goes here....
        }

    }
}
```